# Generator expression including conditional test without calling a function twice?

Tags: python, python-3.x, generator-expression

Suppose I have a function which performs some heavy calculations.

```
def f(x):
    ... 
    return result
```

Then I have a list with values I want to pass to `f()`:

```
my_list = [2, 98, 4, 34, 23, 11]
```

I would like to find the first element `x` in this list which validates a condition on `f(x)` (let's say for example `f(x) != 0`), and get this computed result.

Basically, I would write a `for` loop like this:

```
def first_match(my_list):
    for x in my_list:
        r = f(x)
        if r != 0:
            return r
```

I would like to know if there is a way to get the same result using a generator expression?

What I thought so far was something like this:

```
r = next(f(x) if f(x) != 0 for x in my_list)
```

The issue is that this calls `f()` twice.

Comment: Next time please explain downvote so I can know how to improve my questions in the future... Without any comment it is realy useless.

Comment: Don't take a single downvote seriously. Sometimes people have a bad day, sometimes it's just a missed click. As long as they don't start stacking up, they're meaningless.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a nested generator expression to avoid the double function call:

```
next(y for y in (f(x) for x in my_list) if y != 0)
```

Comment: Why the downvote? This is the only answer so far that actually answers the question.

Comment: won't this call f(x) for all elements in `my_list` first?

Comment: @zyxue: No, it is lazily evaluated. The inner generator expression will only be advanced as far as necessary.

Answer (score 4):

There is a way to use generator expressions, as [already mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32292106/892383) by [Blckknght](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1405065/blckknght), but there's also nothing wrong with the `first_match()` function in your question. Not everything has to be a one-liner :).

Here's another way to do it though:

```
try:
    from itertools import ifilter as filter  # Python 2
except ImportError:
    pass  # Python 3

predicate = lambda x: x != 0
r = next(filter(predicate, (f(x) for x in my_list)), None)
```

The second argument to `next()` (`None` in the above code) is what to return if there's nothing in the iterator that you pass in as the first argument. If you don't specify it and the iterator is exhausted, a `StopIteration` exception will be raised. You can change that to whatever you want.

Comment: And it's easily inlined by putting the lambda right in place.

Comment: @spectras, sure, I just wanted to separate them out for clarity.

Comment: You should also pass a default value argument to `next()` in case `filter()` does not yield anything, avoiding a potential `Stopiteration` exception.

Comment: @plamut, doh, I was going to do that, but I forgot. Thanks :).

Comment: yw, it happens. Besides, you were not the only one, see the answer below yours. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe use [`itertools.ifilter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.ifilter)

```
from itertools import ifilter
next(ifilter(lambda x: f(x) != 0, my_list))
```

Comment: This would return `x`, not `f(x)`.

Answer (score 1):

Comprehensions are possibly nested map functions with option filtration of inputs.  In this case, you want to the filter the output, so do so.  Let y = f(x) = x*x and let c(y) = (y > 100).  Then (y for y in (x*x for x in my_list) if y > 100) gives you the filtered outputs. As you noticed, stopping a filter on the first true element (a first-true search) can be done with next.

```
my_list = [2, 98, 4, 34, 23, 11]
ge = (y for y in (x*x for x in my_list) if y > 100)

print(next(ge))
# 9604
```

Comment: Same comment here, you probably want to pass a default value argument to next() in case the wrapped generator does not return anything to prevent `StopIteration` error from being raised. 
(not that it matters in this particular case, but could be an issue with a different dataset in `my_list`).

Comment: Agreed.  Either that or `try: ... except StopIteration: ...` if there is no good default.

Answer (score 0):

In general, generator expressions can be constructed as a generator function. For example, this f(x) has lazy evaluation as you'd expect from a generator:

```
def f(x):
    for i in x:
        yield i
```

Yes, this is a null delegation, but your example can be employed for your function (which I don't understand the intent of so didn't guess).